# Sum based on multiple row + header criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem with summing up my values from a data set, that's structured like this:

[image]

The goal is to sum the revenues separated by company and split by month, so the result is output in this way

[image]

I have tried it with some =sumifs + index/match and =sumproduct solutions, but can't seem to make it work.

Here's the sample file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16xOoPCHDtcSRRojCkwcBorUc5dstgkXFPR6M_d5uY2U/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "revenues" tab, in cell B4, try using the formula:

```
=SUMIFS(indirect(address(1,match(A4,Overview!$3:$3,0)-1,,,"Overview")&":"&address(1000,match(A4,Overview!$3:$3,0)-1)),Overview!A1:A1000,">="&B$2,Overview!A1:A1000,"<="&B$3)
```

To break it down, this bit helps figure out which revenue column to use by matching the name of the company and then taking the column before that:

```
match(A4,Overview!$3:$3,0)-1
```

This bit creates an address "Overview!$G$1":

```
address(1,match(A4,Overview!$3:$3,0)-1,,,"Overview")
```

This bit creates the 2nd part of the address i.e.":$G$1000":

```
"&":"&address(1000,match(A4,Overview!$3:$3,0)-1)
```

And the rest is a `SUMIFS` where it sums the revenue column for dates after the 1st of the month and before the last date of the month.

---

Be careful: your data is for 2020 and your summary table is using dates in 2021.

#### Reference:

- [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)
- [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en)
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)
- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Comment: Very clever solution!

Answer (score 0):

use in A4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(
 FILTER(Overview!G7:1000, MOD(COLUMN(Overview!G7:1000)+2, 3)=0)="",,
 TEXT(Overview!A7:A25, "m")&"×"&
 FILTER(Overview!G7:1000, MOD(COLUMN(Overview!G7:1000)+2, 3)=0)&"×"&
 FILTER(Overview!G3:3,    MOD(COLUMN(Overview!G3:3)+1, 3)=0))), "×"); 
 SEQUENCE(12), SEQUENCE(12, 2,,)}, 
 "select Col3,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col3 
  pivot Col1", 0), 
 "offset 2", 0))
```

[image]